# How deserialize a generic entity using JSON Schema

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

How deserialize a `JSON` to `HashMap<String, Object>` using her [`JSON` Schema](http://json-schema.org/), for example, dates need to be deserialized with `Date` , not `String`.

Anybody knows how do it? Thank you.

Comment: Should add some examples, what have you tried?